# How to display specific Item First and then rest all in ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have to Display Specific Item first and then rest all in ListView, So how i can do this.

Json Response is Below.

```
{
  "page": 2,
  "per_page": 6,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Michael",
      "last_name": "Lawson",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Lindsay",
      "last_name": "Ferguson",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Tobias",
      "last_name": "Funke",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Byron",
      "last_name": "Fields",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "George",
      "last_name": "Edwards",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Rachel",
      "last_name": "Howell",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "support": {
    "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
    "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
  }
}
```

As above Data suppose i have to display user data first in ListView which id is 10 then after rest all user data.

So how i can do this?

Comment: While Serialization, You can check the id. If it is matching, insert it to first place and rest of other and last.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
   var specifieditem=10;
 fetChdata() {
      var st =
          '{ "page": 2, "per_page": 6, "total": 12, "total_pages": 2, "data": [ { "id": 7, "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in", "first_name": "Michael", "last_name": "Lawson", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg" }, { "id": 8, "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in", "first_name": "Lindsay", "last_name": "Ferguson", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg" }, { "id": 9, "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in", "first_name": "Tobias", "last_name": "Funke", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg" }, { "id": 10, "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in", "first_name": "Byron", "last_name": "Fields", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg" }, { "id": 11, "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in", "first_name": "George", "last_name": "Edwards", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg" }, { "id": 12, "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in", "first_name": "Rachel", "last_name": "Howell", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg" } ], "support": { "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading", "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!" } }';
      var m = MainModel.fromJson(json.decode(st));
         //here we ordering equal 10 member list if unique get one other wise it may be list
      var v10 = m.data!.where((element) => element.id == specifieditem).toList();
              //here get non
      var n10 = m.data!.where((element) => element.id != specifieditem).toList();
         //    we summ both list
      data = v10 + n10;
    }
```

Here we create simple Model class for easy managing you can use `json.decode()` to decode to `map<string,dynamic>` and customize order

```
class MainModel {
  int? page;
  int? perPage;
  int? total;
  int? totalPages;
  List<Data>? data;
  Support? support;

  MainModel(
      {this.page,
      this.perPage,
      this.total,
      this.totalPages,
      this.data,
      this.support});

  MainModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    total = json['total'];
    totalPages = json['total_pages'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    support =
        json['support'] != null ? new Support.fromJson(json['support']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = this.page;
    data['per_page'] = this.perPage;
    data['total'] = this.total;
    data['total_pages'] = this.totalPages;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.support != null) {
      data['support'] = this.support!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  Data({this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['first_name'] = this.firstName;
    data['last_name'] = this.lastName;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    return data;
  }
}

class Support {
  String? url;
  String? text;

  Support({this.url, this.text});

  Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here we use `future builder` widget for fetching from api and ordering if bulkdata for async

```
  FutureBuilder(
                  future: fetChdata(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Center(
                                child: Container(
                                    height: 10,
                                    width: 10,
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                          } else {
                            var data2 = data[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    data2.id.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                    child: Text(data2.firstName.toString() +
                                        data2.lastName.toString()),
                                  )),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                        child: Text(data2.email.toString())),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:
                                    NetworkImage(data2.avatar.toString()),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        });
                  })
```

**sample code** [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=75249229a787b3666066726158783e58)

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()),
  );
}

List<Data> data = [];

fetChdata() {
  var st =
      '{ "page": 2, "per_page": 6, "total": 12, "total_pages": 2, "data": [ { "id": 7, "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in", "first_name": "Michael", "last_name": "Lawson", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg" }, { "id": 8, "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in", "first_name": "Lindsay", "last_name": "Ferguson", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg" }, { "id": 9, "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in", "first_name": "Tobias", "last_name": "Funke", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg" }, { "id": 10, "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in", "first_name": "Byron", "last_name": "Fields", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg" }, { "id": 11, "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in", "first_name": "George", "last_name": "Edwards", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg" }, { "id": 12, "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in", "first_name": "Rachel", "last_name": "Howell", "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg" } ], "support": { "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading", "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!" } }';
  var m = MainModel.fromJson(json.decode(st));
  var v10 = m.data!.where((element) => element.id == 10).toList();

  var n10 = m.data!.where((element) => element.id != 10).toList();

  data = v10 + n10;
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var widgets = [];

  var _mycontroller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          // backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          // bottomNavigationBar: ,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Ordering"),
          ),
          //============

          body: FutureBuilder(
              future: fetChdata(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Center(
                            child: Container(
                                height: 10,
                                width: 10,
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                      } else {
                        var data2 = data[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                data2.id.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                child: Text(data2.firstName.toString() +
                                    data2.lastName.toString()),
                              )),
                            ],
                          ),
                          subtitle: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                    child: Text(data2.email.toString())),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(data2.avatar.toString()),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    });
              })),
    );
  }
}

class MainModel {
  int? page;
  int? perPage;
  int? total;
  int? totalPages;
  List<Data>? data;
  Support? support;

  MainModel(
      {this.page,
      this.perPage,
      this.total,
      this.totalPages,
      this.data,
      this.support});

  MainModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    total = json['total'];
    totalPages = json['total_pages'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    support =
        json['support'] != null ? new Support.fromJson(json['support']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = this.page;
    data['per_page'] = this.perPage;
    data['total'] = this.total;
    data['total_pages'] = this.totalPages;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.support != null) {
      data['support'] = this.support!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  Data({this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['first_name'] = this.firstName;
    data['last_name'] = this.lastName;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    return data;
  }
}

class Support {
  String? url;
  String? text;

  Support({this.url, this.text});

  Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you parse the `data` into `User` objects, you probably have access to the user id of the current user and can simply filter the list from there.

```dart
List<User> allUsers = [...];
int currentUserId = 10;

// get the specific sets to work with
User currentUser = allUsers.firstWhere((user) => user.id == currentUserId);
List<User> otherUsers = allUsers.where((user) => user.id != currentUserId).toList();

return Column(
  children: [
    SingleUserView(user: currentUser),
    ListView.builder(
      itemCount: otherUsers.length,
      builder: (context, index) {
        User user = otherUsers[index];
        return ListUserView(user: user);
      }
    ),
  ],
);
```

Which essentially just uses the `where` and `firstWhere` methods in a `List` to filter it accordingly.

Reading your question again, maybe you meant that you want the first item in the `ListView` to be the `SingleUserView`. That's not too much different and could look like

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: otherUsers.length + 1,
    builder: (context, index) {
      // first item in the ListView is the current user
      if (index == 0) return SingleUserView(user: currentUser);
      
      // otherwise build a card for the current one
      User user = otherUsers[index - 1];
      return ListUserView(user: user);
    }
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it in so many ways; you could also manipulate the **data** array before displaying it, like:

```dart
  var index = data.indexWhere((d) => d['id'] ==10);
  var d = data.removeAt(index);
  data.insert(0, d);
```

You could also build another array and leave the original intact:

```dart
var d = data.where((d) => d['id'] ==10).first;
var rest = data.where((d) => d['id'] != 10).toList();
var newdata = [d, …rest];
```

All in all, I’d advise not to do the logic during the ListView building or even rendering, do it outside, then feed it to the ListView already processed

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final json = {
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Lawson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Lindsay",
        "last_name": "Ferguson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tobias",
        "last_name": "Funke",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Byron",
        "last_name": "Fields",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Edwards",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Rachel",
        "last_name": "Howell",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "support": {
      "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
      "text":
          "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
    }
  };

  List<Model> parsedList = [];
  List<Model> newList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    parsedList = (json["data"] as List).map((e) => Model.fromMap(e)).toList();
    final index = parsedList.indexWhere((element) => element.id == 10);
    newList = [parsedList.removeAt(index), ...parsedList];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: newList.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Text(newList[index].first_name),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Model {
  final int id;
  final String email;
  final String first_name;
  final String last_name;
  final String avatar;

  Model(this.id, this.email, this.first_name, this.last_name, this.avatar);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'email': email,
      'first_name': first_name,
      'last_name': last_name,
      'avatar': avatar,
    };
  }

  factory Model.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Model(
      map['id'] ?? 0,
      map['email'] ?? '',
      map['first_name'] ?? '',
      map['last_name'] ?? '',
      map['avatar'] ?? '',
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Model.fromJson(String source) => Model.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```